# Do Job's tears help with Crohn Disease?

Tags: nutrition, diet, crohns

While my diagnosis is not yet finished and I'll have my final examination at the end of the month, Crohn's Disease looks like the most likely explanation to my condition at the moment, so I decided that it might not hurt to try the diet even before the examination.

Job's Tears mash for a breakfast is a very common recommendation from Chinese medicine for a big variety of issues, I was wondering if anyone has any experience with it, or if someone could explain how it could be helpful/harmful in my case.

Comment: Solely the fact that Chinese medicine recommends it, part of my family lives in China, which is how I came to think about it.

Comment: Currently, there appears to be no evidence of this...